# Use reserved keyword a enum case

Tags: swift, enums

Is it possible to use a reserved keyword as enum case?

For example:

```
enum MyEnum {
  case Self // compiler complains here
  case AnotherCase
}
```

In other languages this is possible by escaping the keyword in some ways, for instance in scala we use backticks, e.g.

```
`type`
```

can be used as identifier, despite `type` being a reserved keyword.

Is there anything similar in swift?

Comment: *"for instance in scala we use backticks ..."* and that is exactly what you can do in Swift as well :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan it needs to match the API response for convenience, it's not something I would do other wise

Comment: Looks like Swift now supports this (maybe added in Swift 2?). Awesome  :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the Swift Language Guide ([Naming Constants & Variables section](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID310))

*If you need to give a constant or variable the same name as a reserved Swift keyword, surround the keyword with back ticks (`) when using it as a name. **However, avoid using keywords as names unless you have absolutely no choice.***

```
enum MyEnum {
  case `Self`
  case AnotherCase
}
```

and use it with or without backticks

```
let x: MyEnum = .Self
let y = MyEnum.`Self`
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I've missed that little box in the docs. Here's the link for future refs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID310

Comment: **However, avoid using keywords as names unless you have absolutely no choice.**  Bolding it in a comment.  Recommending bolding it in the answer.

Comment: @nhgrif Can you explain why? What downsides are there besides having to use backticks when declaring them?