# Swift guard with self

Tags: swift, swift-guard

I am doing the weak strong dance in swift this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), { [weak self] in
    guard let `self` = self else {
        return
    }
    self.doSomething(1)
})
```

Before this, I was using `strongSelf` instead of `self`. On a website I've seen that I can use this character ` .

But what does this character do in Swift? Without this I cannot assign to self. Why does this work? Is it a good practice to use it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315358/use-reserved-keyword-a-enum-case.

Comment: There is a proposal to allow `guard let self = self else { return }` in a future version of Swift: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md, and that your code works is considered a bug in the Swift compiler: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html.

Comment: In practice the entire *guard dance* is pointless because GCD closures don't cause retain cycles.

Comment: Sure, thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID313)

Presents a note that says the following:

> If you need to give a constant or variable the same name as a reserved
>   Swift keyword, surround the keyword with backticks (`) when using it
>   as a name. However, avoid using keywords as names unless you have
>   absolutely no choice.

**EDIT:**

The way I do this is using any other name for example `strongSelf` like you previously did. Because in the end, both `self` and `strongSelf` will be some variable to act upon. So I suggest if we can use some other variable name that is fine.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good information. Do we have any information about how good practice is it to use guard like I described? I see that Apple discourages to use keywords like this, but in this case it really seems to be a good solution. What do you think?

Answer (score 17):

A bit of an update (I will not refer here when to use it but rather how).

**From Swift 4.2** the use should be like:

`guard let self = self else { return }`

Using  `` ` `` is basically based on the compiler bug thus not advised.

For more information there is no better source than [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md). Explaining all reasoning behind and other considerations.

In short the above is more consistent with other cases seen in the code like:

`if let myVariable = myVariable`

So does not create confusion/discrepancies.