# Why is back ticks for default of UIAlertActionStyle enum?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I am a beginner to iOS (came from the Android background). I was looking at the documentation of UIViewController and noticed:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public enum UIPreviewActionStyle : Int {
    case `default`
    case selected
    case destructive
}
```

From Apple doc:

```
case `default` = 0
case cancel = 1
case destructive = 2
```

**I am confused about the back ticks for `'default'`**. Is it different values for the same enum or am I missing something about Swift enum?

Comment: @rmaddy Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315358/use-reserved-keyword-a-enum-case

Comment: @AhmadF That's an even better duplicate. I added it above. Thanks.

Comment: @AhmadF the answer should be (from your link) a reserved keyword can be used as constant/enum case with back ticks (`) and that's what I was missing.

Comment: *"I am confused about the single quotes"* - you mean you are confused about the back ticks. There are no single quotes being used here.

Comment: @maddy I edited my question and yes I was confused about back ticks because I did not know about using the reserved keyword as enum case. That's why asked "am I missing something about swift enum?"

Comment: The Swift language manual is a free download.