# Can we use keywords as parameter names in SWIFT?

Tags: swift, parameters, enums, switch-statement, keyword

Basically, I want to set up a function that uses 'for' as a parameter for readability.

```
enum Genre {
    case drama
    case comedy
}

func setupTable(for: Genre) {
    switch for {
    case .drama: break
    case .comedy: break
    }
}
```

I set something like this up but when i try and use the switch for 'for' it comes up as a keyword and throws a compile error.

Cheers

Comment: Usually in this case, you'd give the parameter a different internal name: `func setupTable(for genre: Genre)`. Then say `switch genre`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315358/use-reserved-keyword-a-enum-case

Comment: Good to know that it can be used project wide and not just in this particular case by using back ticks but I feel  using reserved keywords as names should be refrained from if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a keyword as a normal identifier you have to escape it using backticks ` like this

```
func setupTable(for: Genre) {
    switch `for` {
        case .drama: break
        case .comedy: break
    }
}
```

---

On a side note, as pointed out by @Hamish in a comment on the question, you should try to avoid using such names for variables, which (in this case) you can do by providing both an internal and external name for the parameter:

```swift
func setupTable(for genre: Genre) {
    switch genre {
        case .drama: break
        case .comedy: break
    }
}
```