# Why can't I put an enum case in single quotes which is of type Int?

Tags: swift, enums

I'm following a tutorial and it says to type in the code below:

```
import UIKit

enum Theme: Int {
  //1
  case `default`, dark, graphical

  //2
  private enum Keys {
    static let selectedTheme = "SelectedTheme"
  }

  //3
  static var current: Theme {
    let storedTheme = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: Keys.selectedTheme)
    return Theme(rawValue: storedTheme) ?? .default
  }
}
```

This seemed to be fine and well however I began researching online what exactly an enum in Swift is.  One piece of information I found online said that I could break out each case on its own line as shown below:

```
import UIKit


//We're creating an enum!
enum Theme: Int {

  //1
  case 'default'
  case dark
  case graphical

  //2
  private enum Keys {
    static let selectedTheme = "SelectedTheme"
  }


}
```

However I get a compile time error that says 'Expected identifier in enum 'case' declaration and I'm not sure what this means.  Can anyone please explain why can't I break out each case on its own line in this example?

Comment: "default" is a keyword, as an enum case it has to be enclosed in *backticks* (as in the first example), not in single quotes (as in your second example)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the fine comment above for help.  The reason is because the word "default" is a keyword that is reserved in the Swift language therefore in order to use it within my own program in a different way than suggested by the Swift language then I will need to place with word within backticks.  See this SO question for reference: [Use reserved keyword a enum case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315358/use-reserved-keyword-a-enum-case)